# how to bypass internal DNS?

Tags: virtualhost, internal-dns, host

This is about Ubuntu but should be pretty much the same on all Linux flavors. Let's say I add an entry to my `/etc/hosts` such as

```
127.0.1.12   facebook.com
```

and an Apache virtual host such as

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.12>
   ServerName facebook.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

when i open my browser and send a GET request to facebook.com, firefox will browse my /var/www folder.

Question:
How could I fetch (ie, using wget in bash) the real facebook.com domain - without erasing the entry in /etc/hosts nor my Apache VirtualHost -- IOW how could I bypass internal DNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the best setup is the other way around - Setup a DNS server with zones for the sites you want to spoof and point clients to your DNS server.  Then you can set an outside set of servers in /etc/resolv.conf on your web server, or add a hosts entry pointing to the real site.

Comment: that's a really good idea! I wasn't thinking outside the box! I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation :( thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, replace this:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

with this:

```
hosts:          dns
```